# jquery mouse leave conflict with another div

Tags: jquery

Please refer the fiddle: [Refer this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kLte6zzk/)

```
$("#shopid").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        //stuff to do on mouse enter
        $(".leftmenu").show();
    },
    mouseleave: function (e) {
        //stuff to do on mouse leave
        $(".leftmenu").hide();
    }
});
```

If mouse enter in the `open menu area` (`shopid` ) the menu opens. if I mouse leave the `shopid` the menu closes.

If the mouse is inside the menu area (ul li), the sub menu should not close. But I couldn't hover the sub menu (ul li). It closes. How to fix this.

I tried the following to achieve this. But not working

```
if ($(".leftmenu").has(e.target).length > 0 ) { $(".leftmenu").hide(); }
```

Comment: It must have a reason why you cannot post a jsFiddle link without posting code in question, don't you think?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` are not suited when the items are positioned in unrelated parts of the DOM (as per your updated commment) and potentially overlapping. This will cause all sorts of false triggers or `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` events just being skipped.

Instead you can listen for the `mousemove` on an ancestor of both elements (I used `document` in the absence of any other details). You then test whether the item under the mouse is one of the required panels (or a child of them), using `closest`.

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/kLte6zzk/4/

```
$(document).on({
    mousemove: function (e) {
        if (!$(e.target).closest('#shopid,.leftmenu').length)
        {
            $(".leftmenu").hide();
        }
        else
        {
            $(".leftmenu").show();
        }
    }
});
```

Which can be reduced further using `toggle`

```
$(document).on({
    mousemove: function (e) {
        $(".leftmenu").toggle($(e.target).closest('#shopid,.leftmenu').length > 0);
    }
});
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/kLte6zzk/6/

Comment: No. Don't  place the submenu div inside the container. Its not my criteria. All are in separate places. I tried with this code if ($(".leftmenu").has(e.target).length > 0 ) 
{
     $(".leftmenu").hide();
}

Comment: @Sam Hanson: So basically, you have posted a JSFiddle that looks nothing like the real situation... and we were supposed to know that how? :)

Comment: I couldn't post my entire code here. So only I create the rough draft here. :) Do you need any further details for this?

Comment: @Sam Hanson: Answer updated to work with your newly described scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Add this into your CSS first

```
#shopid ul {
    margin-top: 150px;
}
```

change

```
<div id="shopid" style="width:300px; height:150px; background-color:#990000">openmenu</div>
```

to

```
<div id="shopid" style="width:300px; height:150px; background-color:#990000">openmenu
```

and close the above divider after the list

```
</ul>
</div>
```

This means that the list is now a child element of the shopid meaning that the mouseenter/mouseout does not interfere with this element and will perform as you require it to do so.

https://jsfiddle.net/kLte6zzk/1/

fiddle reference ^